# There are no configured ssh keys to install CIRCLE CI

Tags: circleci

I have configured my ssh keys in circle ci, and I m also adding  it in my config.yml like this:

```
  steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "My fingerprint"
```

But during the cicd it throws this message: 'There are no configured ssh keys to install'

By The way, it was working fine the entire last month.

Any clue? Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: Yep, sorry for the delay. It stopped working after I used the same ssh keys in other CICD flow, no Idea why. I just recreated my EC2 with brand new ssh keys and everything went back to normal

Comment: Running into the same issue. A fresh machine-user ssh key was creating via the CircleCi project settings page. Still no dice.

Comment: Having this problem now, it is so freaking infuriating.